# Bubble Sort Algorithm - Scilab

Tags: algorithm, sorting, scilab

I'm a first year computing student and can't get my function to work properly.  I'm getting undisclosed errors and don't know why.

I've had it working but it didn't display the list at the end or allow me to use %T and %F for my 'escape' boolean variable.

Any thoughts?

```
function x=sort(n,y);
disp("Enter numbers");
for i = 1:n
    x(i) = input('');
end

escape = 0;

if y == 1 then
    while escape == 0
        escape = 1;
        for i = 1:n
            if x(i+1) < x(i) then
                temp = x(i);
                x(i) = x(i+1);
                x(i+1) = temp;
                escape = 0;
            end
        end
    end
end

if y == 2 then
    while escape == 0
        escape = 1;
        for i == 1:n
            if x{i+1} > x{i} then
                temp = x{i};
                x{i} = x{i+1};
                x{i+1} = temp;
                escape = 0;
            end
        end
    end
end

disp(x(:));
endfunction;

a=input("Enter the number of values to sort: ");
b=input("Enter 1 for ascending, 2 for descending: ")
disp(sort(a,b));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because you have incorrect syntax on various places (extra semicolons, `==` operator instead of `=` operator in for statement, `{}` bracket where `()` brackets should be, etc.). Moreover your `for` cycle must be from `1` to `n-1` to avoid "invalid index" error

```
function x=sort(n,y)
disp("Enter numbers")
for i = 1:n
    x(i) = input('')
end

escape = %f

if y == 1 then
    while escape == %f
        escape = %t
        for i = 1:n-1
            if x(i+1) < x(i) then
                temp = x(i)
                x(i) = x(i+1)
                x(i+1) = temp
                escape = %f
            end
        end
    end
end

if y == 2 then
    while escape == %f
        escape = %t
        for i = 1:n-1
            if x(i+1) > x(i) then
                temp = x(i)
                x(i) = x(i+1)
                x(i+1) = temp
                escape = %f
            end
        end
    end
end

endfunction

a=input("Enter the number of values to sort: ")
b=input("Enter 1 for ascending, 2 for descending: ")
disp(sort(a,b))
```

Comment: You beautiful person.

I only started using Scilab yesterday for a project after spending years on Pascal and Java, it's an awkward transition.